# Unable to pass props to component through react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am unable to pass props using react-router. My code till now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import './styles/styles.scss';

const EditExpensePage = props => {
  console.log(props);

  return <div>Editing the expense with id of </div>;
};

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById('appDiv'));
```

**Error screenshot**

[image: Error screenshot]

**I am trying to access the *id* in console as simple as that.**

The error is showing only when I am trying to pass props

```
path="/edit/:id"
```

Source Link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

Comment: Depends what props do you need. If id for your case you can use params https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match. To pass additional props use `render` instead of `component` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev I am trying to get the following value in console for now: {props.match.params.id}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575467/when-i-link-javascript-file-in-html-it-sends-a-request-to-server-and-causing-err). The problem is specific to the setup. As shown in error message, `bundle.js` is loaded from current path, `/edit/bundle.js`, while it should be loaded from `/bundle.js`.

Scripts should either have absolute paths:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Or base URL should be specified:

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with your local environment, I dont see anyproblem with your code. I tried out in https://codesandbox.io/s/ox773ywmn9 and there is no issue

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it but any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can access the props in the child components using this:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in how this may help answer the OPs question?