# React component throws an error after refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having a trouble with this minor problem . When i refresh my page , it gives an error `

> GET http://localhost:3000/drink/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/drink/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I know that this a problem with rout but i couldnt find a way to solve it .
Here is my code `

```
import * as React from "react"; import {connect} from "react-redux"; import {drinksSelector} from "../selectors" import {getDrinksList, getNameFilter} from "../actions"; import Drink from "./Drink"; import SearchIcon from "./SvgIcons";

class Drinks extends React.Component { 
    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.dispatchDrinksList();   
  }

  handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatchNameFilter(e.target.value)   }

  render() {
    const {drinks} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="main-header">
          <form className="main-header__from">
            <div className="search-wrapper">
              <input autoComplete='off'
                type="text" 
                name="search" 
                placeholder="Search" 
                className="main-header__input" 
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
          </form>
        </header>
        <ul>
          {drinks.map((drink: any) => <Drink key={drink.idDrink} url={drink.strDrinkThumb} name={drink.strDrink} id={drink.idDrink}/>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );   } } const mapStateToProps: any = (state: any) => drinksSelector(state);

const mapDispatchToProps: any = (dispatch: ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>) => ({   dispatchDrinksList() {
    dispatch(getDrinksList());   },

  dispatchNameFilter(value: any) {
    dispatch(getNameFilter(value));   
  } });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Drinks);
```

Above is the dashboard page where i render list of drinks, and when clicking on them the routes changes to `/drink/someId`

```
import * as React from 'react'; import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Drink = ({ url = "", name, id }: any): any => (
    <li>
      <NavLink to={`/drink/${id}`}>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <img src={url} alt={name} height="350" width="350"/>
      </NavLink>
    </li>    );

export default Drink;
```

And this is the page where after refreshing i got an error `

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import {getDrinkInfo} from "../actions";

class DrinkInfo extends React.Component<any, any> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const id = localStorage.getItem("id");
    if (!id) {
      localStorage.setItem("id", this.props.match.params.id);
    }
    this.props.dispatchDrinkInfo(localStorage.getItem("id"));
  }

  render() {
    const { drink } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    return (
      <div className="drink-info">
        <header className="drink-info__header">
          <button onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()} className="drink-info__button">Go Back</button>
          <h2 className="drink-info__title">{drink && drink.strDrink}</h2>
        </header>
        <section className="details">
          <div className="details__image-box">
            <img src={drink && drink.strDrinkThumb} alt={drink && drink.strDrink} height="350" width="350"/>
          </div>
          <div className="details__info">
            <p className="details__ingredients"></p>
            <div className="details__prepare">
              <h3 className="details__prepare-heading">How to prepare</h3>
              <p className="details__prepare-text">
                {drink && drink.strInstructions}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps: any = (state: any) => {
    return {
      drink: state.drink.get("drinkInfo") || {}
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps: any = (dispatch: ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>) => ({
  dispatchDrinkInfo(id: number) {
    dispatch(getDrinkInfo(id));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DrinkInfo);
```

My routers `

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardPage from '../components/DashboardPage';
import DrinkInfo from '../components/DrinkInfo';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';

const AppRouter = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={DashboardPage} exact/>
            <Route path="/drink/:id" component={DrinkInfo}/>
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Where's your index?  Seems like you're issue is you're using a relative path to your assets instead of an absolute url or root relative url.

Comment: Index is being created  after compile , why do i need to change something there ?

Comment: I think its a problem with routes ... when refresh , the url is changing to "localhost:3000/drink/" , so why it throughs an error . i just need to add **id** to the url after refreshing

Comment: I dont serve my assets from any backend service , its just client side react and nothing more ... I  just give webpack an html template which will use for rendering my actual html

Comment: You won't be able to use React app without backend service. React app already uses web server to serve it at 3000 port. And whatever your HTML template is, it needs to be fixed to contain either absolute paths to resources or `<base>` tag. This is also exactly same problem as you have, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652521/unable-to-pass-props-to-component-through-react-router